# Prevent auto scroll to the top on pasting in a google sheet embedded in an iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

One solution was setting position of the iframe as fixed. But this messes up my web page.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question right you want the iframe content to not scroll which is sadly not possible because you can't use Scripts on iframes.